# Cannot execute python with node exec

Tags: python, node.js, child-process

Using node's `child-spawn` `exec` basically mimics the shell, so I should be able to do

```
exec('python' , (error, stdout, stderr) => { 
  if (error || stderr) {
    console.log('exec error ' , error )
    console.log('exec stderr ' ,  stderr)
  } else {
    console.log('exec output ' , stdout)
  }
})
```

or

```
exec('python hello.py' , (error, stdout, stderr) => { 
  //same as above
```

but I get nothing back, not even errors.

What am I missing here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`python` command expects some data to be written to stdin. You can write that data by using the subprocess object returned by `exec`:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const subprocess = exec('python' , (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error || stderr) {
    console.log('exec error ' , error )
    console.log('exec stderr ' ,  stderr)
  } else {
    console.log('exec output ' , stdout)
  }
})

subprocess.stdin.write('print("test");');
subprocess.stdin.end()
```

Probably `hello.py` also waits for some data.